# Speed up creation of hundreds of buttons at runtime

Tags: qt

I'm creating hundred of buttons at runtime and adding them into layout. Each operation probably trigger many things (repaint, layout rebuild etc) which are not necessary for each button but could be called once add the end when all buttons are created. In Lazarus world (open-source Delphi alternative) is DisableAutoSizing / EnableAutoSizing for form which "hold on" time-consuming triggers. Can't find anything similar for Qt.
I need also such functionality in another case. Let's say that you have complicated UI with a lot of widgets (with childs etc) and you want to totally rearrange UI (change layout, move widgets into another layouts etc). Normally I sometimes see "flickering". I would like to stop application painting - rearrange widgets - enable painting

Edit: Found something `setUpdatesEnabled()` . Is there anything else?

Comment: please tell me for what would you need hundreds of buttons for?

Comment: no I just can't think of anything that would require you to create hundreds of buttons at once, there's gotta be a better way.

Comment: This is an XY issue.  If your solution to a UI problem is to create _hundreds_ of buttons - your solution is wrong.

Comment: There is also `QLayout::setEnabled` but it doesn't seem to help. The simpliest solution is to hide the widget before adding buttons. If you don't want to hide main window, put a container widget in the form and hide it instead.